# OGR Error : Silly size requested

Tags: ogr2ogr, sqlite, tab

I'm scripting OGR functionality in order to filter some mapinfo tables and convert them into sqlite files.

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLITE" newtest.sqlite test.tab -sql "SELECT cols FROM test WHERE .."
```

where TAB file is about 2GB size (including ID,MAP,DAT & TAB extensions within)

I receive error like this :

```
ERROR 1: CPLRealloc(-1532233231): Silly size requested.
```

What does it mean exactly,how to resolve this ?

Comment: have you tried your query without the SQL. I have successfully loaded 10Gb of data into an SQLite before, so I doubt it is the SQLite that is causing your issues. I would use the following command ogr2ogr -progress -f "SQLite" -gt 56000 newtest.sqlite test.tab and see whether it even starts loading the data

Comment: I tried to give a larger size for -gt option,still the same error,without sql i cannot continue process.I can just remove where clause that directed to same error before process even began to work

Comment: Also removed -sql option,still the same

Comment: maybe try to convert into an ESRI Shapefile, if that fails maybe your MapInfo TAB is corrupt. Do you have a GIS that could open the TAB file and export to a different format?

Comment: TAB file is OK,I have opened with Mapinfo.

Comment: While I doubt this helps much, it looks like an overflow error on a signed 4-byte integer.